# why php doesn't get updated to the latest version on my server?

Tags: shell, upgrade, php, updates, sudo

here's phpinfo() of my server:

http://www.rimmer.sk/phpinfo.php

when I login to the server as root and do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, let it run completely, all finishes OK.

When I try to run it again, it says that all is updated.

Yet, my php version is still 5.2.6. Can anyone help me why? How do I run a (better?) update?

EDIT: I did a `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` after the upgrade, of course.

EDIT2:

What do I need to change in this file to be able to upgrade to squeeze?

```
#
#  /etc/apt/sources.list
#


#
# lenny
#
deb     http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/     lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/     lenny main contrib non-free

#
#  Security updates
#
deb     http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates  main contrib non-free
```

Comment: is this debian lenny?  why do you need/want a newer version of php?  do you need 5.3?  are you just after something newer for the sake of it being newer?

Comment: yes, I don't really _need_ it, I just want to keep the system up to date, if possible

Comment: then I'd recommend sticking with what is in debian, as debian will be backporting security fixes to that version. if you switch to something outside of debian, you'll have to keep an eye out for security fixes yourself.  alternatively, consider upgrading instead to the current version of stable: 6.0 aka squeeze, which would have 5.3.  see: http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html

Comment: could you please help me by answering my edit2 ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update to a version higher than the ones available in configured repositories. Either add a repository with a higher version, or install it manually from a package or source.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of adding a repository with a higher version?

Comment: The pro is that you get the higher version. The con is that you may get higher versions of other packages which you may or may not want.

Comment: No chance of any incompatibilities happening ? I mean with other 'parts of the system'. It's an online server with more than 100 websites running on it, I wouldn't like to risk breaking it.

Comment: Of course there are chances of incompatibilities. PHP is not always backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to upgrade debian completely to a newer version, then I 'received' the latest php version.